# Converting Voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I have a pair of batteries that can operate at 7.2V (series) or 3.6V (parallel) and I need to power up a device using 5V.  I can use a Voltage Regulator to down voltage at 5V or I can use maybe transistors to up voltage at 5V.
Which is more efficient?, what would you recommend for power up that circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those voltages they are LiIon or LiPO - same for practical purposes.

Vmean is ... 3.6 V
Vmax is  ....4.2 V
Vmin about ..3.0 V (safely)

So 2S = 6 min, 7.2 mean, 8.4 max

With a 5V linear regulator efficiencies at those voltages are
V __ Eff__  Eff%
6.0 ..... 5/6  = 83%
7.2 ... 5/7.2 = 69%
8.4 ... 5/8.4 = 60%

The average is probably around 70%
With a good boost converter you can ge high 8x% and with a very good one low 9x%

So with a say 85% boost converter the gain in available energy over a linear regulator is 85/70 = ~~~ 20% more energy.

The linear regulator is very simple and easy.
The boost converter may be easy. Or not.

What power level? 
What sort of load?

Comment: Nice Answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a 3rd solution, the buck-boost - this has the advantage of allowing you to connect your batteries in series or parallel: -

[image]

A higher current output version here: -

[image]